# can i host asp.net web site in linux server?

Tags: asp.net, linux, web, host

How can i host asp.net website in linux server..
I am hosting asp.net website in linux server but it gives code error. You can see the screen short to better understand.

[image].

Comment: That is not an error code. That's just the raw markup. If you look up "ASP.NET on Linux" you'll find plenty of step by step tutorials.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can host site in only two ways:

1. You use ASP.NET with Mono.
2. You use ASP.NET Core.

The second way is the most preferred but each of them are unstable and don't suitable for production. Use ASP.NET only with Windows Server with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Although to avoid huge problems and configuration issues Windows server is used all over the world to host ASP.NET apps.

How ever you can explore [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to use Linux to host ASP.NET Webapps.

Hope this helps.